# Allow user to select the number of checkboxes equal to the value of a text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

you want help me, I have a form where I have an input text and 4 chechbox, what I do is, if you write a value in the input, is the same number of checked I can make the checkbox, eg write the value 3 in the input and in the group of checkbox only allows me to select any 3 boxes and missing fourth box is off or you can not do checked.

thanks and regards.

HTML:

```
    <input id="iddata_13561" name="data_13561" type="text" value="" >

    <input name="data" id="iddata_13562" type="checkbox"  value="1">
    <input name="data" id="iddata_13570" type="checkbox"  value="1">
    <input name="data" id="iddata_13578" type="checkbox"  value="1">
    <input name="data" id="iddata_13586" type="checkbox"  value="1">
```

JS:

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
           $("input[name='tech']").change(function () {

              var maxAllowed = $('#iddata_13561').attr('value');

              var cnt = $("input[name='tech']:checked").length;

             if (cnt > maxAllowed)
              {
                 $(this).prop("checked", "");
                 alert('Select maximum ' + maxAllowed + ' technologies!');
             }
          });
        });
```

Comment: `input[name='tech']` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4):

You don't want the attribute `value`, you want the current value.  For that you use `val`:

```
var maxAllowed = $('#iddata_13561').val();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/efKAb/

**Note**: I changed `name='data'` to `tech` as I assume that was a copy/paste error.